# How to make a sql view where each row is the result of a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I am currently working on PostgreSQL version 14.
I got two tables, one is a list of emails, the other one describe if those emails are invalid or was marked as unsubscribe (black_list). I want to make the percentage of how many addresses are invalid and unsubscribed in two different rows in the same table using a view.

My email table

```
| email_id | email|
|:---- |:------:|
| 1| bob.smith@yahoo.com|
| 2| ronald.gregor@gmail.com|
| 3| jo123456@gmail.com|
```

My table black_list looks like that.

| email_id | unsubscribe | invalid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False |
| 3 | False | True |

The result I expect.

| categories | value |
| --- | --- |
| unsubscribe | 33 |
| invalid | 33 |

I tried to make a view with this query :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW percentage_unsubscribe (value) AS SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM black_list WHERE unsubscribe = True)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM email_table
```

But i would like to know how to pass the categorical column and the second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union` to generate two rows and the `with` statement to optimize the query a bit and make it more readable, e.g.:

```sql
create or replace view percentage_unsubscribe (category, value) as 
    with totals as (
        select
            count(*) filter (where unsubscribe) as unsubscribe,
            count(*) filter (where invalid) as invalid,
            (select count(*) from email_table) as total
        from black_list
    )
    select 'unsubscribe', unsubscribe* 100/ total
    from totals
    union
    select 'invalid', invalid* 100/ total
    from totals;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It does work perfectly. Just too be sure I understood the logic behind your query correctly, first you get the information in the "as ( select" , and then you define what to put in each row with select column and union for each row ?

Comment: @Adikte - Exactly. As a result, the query scans the tables only once.